List in tblr environment and text specifications
How do I make a list in tblr environment such that text is justified and vertically aligned in the center?
Is this also the correct way to stack two equations in one cell?
\documentclass[9pt, landscape, twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}[English]

\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{latexsym}
% \usepackage{array}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

% \usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most,listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colframe=white}

\usepackage{multirow}

% Margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=0.75in,
right=0.75in,
top=1in,
bottom=1in
}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Juan Da Silva}
\lhead{Machine Learning}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{TUM}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying


\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

% Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, ext.paths.ortho, backgrounds, fit, calc}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines, vlines,
        cells={valign=m},
        rowsep=5pt,
        colspec={cp{2cm}X[c]X[c]},
        row{1}={mode=text},
        row{2}={mode=dmath},
        row{3}={mode=text},
        row{4}={mode=text}
    }
        Mode & Valid & Same & Full \\
        \textrm{Value} & P = 0 & 
        \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} % Nested array for multiple equations
            P_{\textrm{start}} = \left\lfloor \frac{S\lceil\frac{I}{S}\rceil -I+F-S}{2}\right\rfloor \\
            P_{\textrm{end}} = \left\lceil \frac{S\lceil\frac{I}{S}\rceil -I+F-S}{2}\right\rceil
        \end{array} & 
        \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
            P_{\textrm{start}} \in [0, F-1] \\
            P_{\textrm{end}} = F
        \end{array}\\
        Purpose &
            \SetCell[c=1]{l}{\item No padding. \\
            \item Drops last convolution if dimensions do not match.} &
            \SetCell[c=1]{l}{\item Padding such that feature map size has size $\lceil \frac{I}{S} \rceil$. \\
            \item Output size is mathematically convenient.} &
            \SetCell[c=1]{l}{\item Maximum padding such that end convolutions are applied on the limits of the input. \\
            \item Filter `sees' the input end-to-end.}
    \end{tblr}
    \par}

    
\end{document}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, I thought I did

Thanks for the update! Can you clarify which list should be changed? I don't see a list any of your cells.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz When edited the post I accidentally deleted the \item commands. They just serve as a reference, since I tried to use an itemize environment and it didn't work

If you use fixed width columns, you can use lists without any complications:
\documentclass[landscape, twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \noindent\begin{tblr}{
        hlines, vlines,
        cells={valign=m},
        rowsep=5pt,
        colspec={XQ[.29\linewidth,c]Q[.29\linewidth,c]Q[.29\linewidth,c]},
        row{2}={halign=l}
    }
        Mode & Valid & Same & Full \\
        Purpose &
        \begin{itemize}
          \item No padding. 
          \item Drops last convolution if dimensions do not match.
        \end{itemize} &
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Padding such that feature map size has size $\lceil \frac{I}{S} \rceil$. 
          \item Output size is mathematically convenient.
        \end{itemize}
         &
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Maximum padding such that end convolutions are applied on the limits of the input.
          \item Filter `sees' the input end-to-end.
        \end{itemize} 
        \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}


